# Set TimeOut to a higher value in Microsoft.Graph SDK

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-api

I get timeout error frequently with the below code using the Microsoft.Graph package,

```
await graphServiceClient.Users[UserId].Contacts.Request().AddAsync(contact);
```

As there are no option (that I could find) for adding multiple contacts at a time, I was calling the above LOC parallel. I have around say 500 contacts to import and many of them fails giving the timeout response

> Exception: Code: timeout Message: The request timed out.

Are there any option to set TimeOut to a higher value in Microsoft.Graph GraphServiceClient?

Comment: How many are you attempting to send in parallel?

Comment: I have the same exception in similar situation. I'm doing parallel request for file information from `Microsoft.Graph` and when cancel it with `CancellationToken`, I receive this exception. MsGraph version 1.7.0

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can set the Timeout to a higher value like this:
For example to set the Timeout to one hour:

```
graphServiceClient.HttpProvider.OverallTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
```