# Microsoft Graph API - MultiThreading timeout

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am working on a solution which download all the files of a SharePoint library using Microsoft Graph API.
I am using one `GraphServiceClient` to do all my requests.

I am multithreading all the downloads and at some points I am getting timeout error `Code: timeout Message: The request timed out.`. I have found this post [Set TimeOut to a higher value in Microsoft.Graph SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43260659/set-timeout-to-a-higher-value-in-microsoft-graph-sdk) which is showing how to set a higher `OverallTimeout` for the HttpProvider of my `GraphServiceClient` but I'd prefer to be able to set a TimeOut over the request I suspect that will trigger the TimeOut.

Is there a way to do so? What have I missed? Or is it even possible? I haven't found yet the answer in the MSDN, SO or in the Graph C# library.

Comment: How many concurrent downloads do you have, maybe limit the number?

Comment: I made the number of download manageable. I tried with around 75 to 100 concurrent downloads to find the limit. As I saw the possibility to increase the HttpProvider TimeOut (which works to fix my "problem"), I assumed there were a way to increase it directly on the `Request()`

Comment: Nice. In above scenario's always i will go with a small limits/batches instead of higher numbers, as i dont want to make my application getting throttled or avoid any other issues.